# Simple nicEdit is not working at all without any error

Tags: javascript, richtextbox

I am trying to use nicEdit to create a simple textarea editor. But its not working and also not giving any error.

Here is the link
http://aht.com.pk/temp/html/index.html

Check the Rich Text Editor for Description, type something and hit bold or underline etc button. Whats wrong?

Here is my html

```
<textarea name="description">Sample text</textarea>
```

and js

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);
```

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this.

```
 bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
```

Don't forget to include `nicEdit-latest.js` and put  above code inside `<script>` tag.